# VMWare power failure guests don't connect to internal network?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi server running basic network services, i.e. firewall, domain controller, dhcp, dns, disk shares, etc.  The guest OS's are set up to come online in the following order: firewall, domain controller, everything else.

We recently experienced a power failure.  All OS's came online in (I presume) the correct order, however, the internal network was disconnected.  All OS's have the box checked for "connect at power on", however, no services were available, and when I finally set my desktop to a manual IP address and logged in to the VMWare server, I discovered that the checkbox for "Connected" on all interfaces for the internal network were unchecked.  The external network (internet) seemed to be just fine.

Needless to say, this is not an ideal situation.  If I had not been in the office at the time this power failure occurred, all internal services would be more or less unrecoverable.

Is this a setting somewhere or a bug, and how to make sure it does not happen again? (it seems a bug - how can you have "connect at power on" not connect you at power on?)

- ESXi version is 5.1.0, build 799733.
- Guest OS's are:

  - 3X Ubuntu 12.10 server, (file storage, databases, internal web services)
  - Firewall is a custom FreeBSD implementation (pfSense 2.0.3-RELEASE)
  - DC/ DNS/ DHCP is Windows 2003 Standard SP2

Networking is set up as follows:

[image: vm Network setup]

Comment: what version of esxi?

Comment: Please provide ESXi version, the *operating systems* of the VMs installed and the networking setup. A screenshot of your vSwitch configuration would be helpful.

Comment: @ewwhite updated as per your request.

Answer (score 3):

[Update your ESXi installation](http://www.vmware.com/patchmgr/download.portal?rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.vmware.com/go/downloadpatches&ei=_c6OUfAdqa7JAZemgfAE&usg=AFQjCNEIHccddkleB6hOSnNbc3Fj3-VlwQ&sig2=KNThdfMTKOSyscO4CnEcxw) to the current build to get around any particular bugs - Right now, the current build is #1065491, so you're behind.

Do you have VMware tools installed inside of your guest virtual machines? You'll want that. For Ubuntu (and other Linux) systems, I prefer to use the VMware OSP packages to handle the tools. [**See this post for details**](https://serverfault.com/questions/506618/how-to-detect-in-the-guest-operating-system-if-the-vmware-tools-are-out-of-dat/506627#506627).

Finally, ***test this!!*** 

For a standalone host, make sure your VM startup/shutdown order is proper. Run a scheduled shutdown and startup of the host.

[image]

Comment: I do have the vmware tools installed on all the systems;  I will reply back when I get a maintenance window and try this.