# How do I make sure VMware Tools is installed and running?

Tags: redhat, vmware-esxi, vmware-tools

```
[root@tst-01 ~]# rpm -qa |grep vmware
vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2.x86_64
vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4.x86_64
vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2.x86_64
[root@tst-01 ~]# ps aux |grep vmware
root      6615  0.0  0.0 103300   840 pts/2    S+   15:48   0:00 grep vmware
[root@tst-01 ~]# locate vmware
/etc/vmware-tools
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/vmware.pp
/etc/vmware-tools/locations
/lib/modules/2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/misc/vmware_balloon.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/misc/vmware_balloon.ko
/usr/lib/vmware-tools
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sos/plugins/vmware.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sos/plugins/vmware.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sos/plugins/vmware.pyo
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/bin
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/dsp
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/xorg
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/bin/configure-gtk.sh
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXau.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXcomposite.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXcursor.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXdamage.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXdmcp.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXfixes.so.3
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXft.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXinerama.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXrandr.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXrender.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXss.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libart_lgpl_2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libatkmm-1.6.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libcairo.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libcairomm-1.0.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libdnet.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libexpat.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libfontconfig.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libfreetype.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libfuse.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgailutil.so.18
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgiomm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgksu2.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglade-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgnomecanvas-2.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgnomecanvasmm-2.6.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgtop-2.0.so.7
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangomm-1.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangox-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpixman-1.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpng12.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libproc-3.2.7.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/librsvg-2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libsexy.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libsexymm.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libsigc-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libspi.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libstartup-notification-1.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/liburiparser.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libview.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXau.so.6/libXau.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXcomposite.so.1/libXcomposite.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXcursor.so.1/libXcursor.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXdamage.so.1/libXdamage.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXdmcp.so.6/libXdmcp.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXfixes.so.3/libXfixes.so.3
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXft.so.2/libXft.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXinerama.so.1/libXinerama.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXrandr.so.2/libXrandr.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXrender.so.1/libXrender.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libXss.so.1/libXss.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libart_lgpl_2.so.2/libart_lgpl_2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0/libatk-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libatkmm-1.6.so.1/libatkmm-1.6.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0/libbonobo-2.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4/libbonobo-activation.so.4
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libcairo.so.2/libcairo.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libcairomm-1.0.so.1/libcairomm-1.0.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libdnet.so.1/LICENSE
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libdnet.so.1/libdnet.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libexpat.so.0/libexpat.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libfontconfig.so.1/libfontconfig.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libfreetype.so.6/libfreetype.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libfuse.so.2/libfuse.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgailutil.so.18/libgailutil.so.18
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0/libgio-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgiomm-2.4.so.1/libgiomm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgksu2.so.0/libgksu2.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglade-2.0.so.0/libglade-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgnomecanvas-2.so.0/libgnomecanvas-2.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgnomecanvasmm-2.6.so.1/libgnomecanvasmm-2.6.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0/libgthread-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libgtop-2.0.so.7/libgtop-2.0.so.7
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0/libpango-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangomm-1.4.so.1/libpangomm-1.4.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangox-1.0.so.0/libpangox-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpcsclite.so.1.0.0/libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpixman-1.so.0/libpixman-1.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libpng12.so.0/libpng12.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libproc-3.2.7.so/libproc-3.2.7.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/librsvg-2.so.2/librsvg-2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libsexy.so.2/libsexy.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libsexymm.so.2/libsexymm.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libsigc-2.0.so.0/libsigc-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libspi.so.0/libspi.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8/libssl.so.0.9.8
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libstartup-notification-1.so.0/libstartup-notification-1.so.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libstdc++.so.6/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/liburiparser.so.1/liburiparser.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libview.so.2/libview.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libxml2.so.2/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/fonts
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/pango
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/fonts/fonts.dtd
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/gtk-2.0/gdk-pixbuf.loaders
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/gtk-2.0/gtk.immodules
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/gtk-2.0/im-multipress.conf
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/pango/pango.modules
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/pango/pango.modules.toolchain
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/pango/pangorc
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/pango/pangorc.toolchain
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/etc/pango/pangox.aliases
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/modules
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libclearlooks.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-am-et.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-cedilla.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-cyrillic-translit.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-inuktitut.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ipa.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-multipress.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-thai.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ti-er.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ti-et.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-viqr.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-xim.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-ani.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-bmp.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-gif.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-icns.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-ico.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-jpeg.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-pcx.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-pnm.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-qtif.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-ras.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-tga.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-tiff.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-wbmp.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-xbm.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-xpm.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/svg_loader.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/modules/libatk-bridge.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/modules/libferret.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/gtk-2.0/modules/libgail.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-arabic-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-arabic-lang.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-x.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-hangul-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-hebrew-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-indic-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-indic-lang.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-khmer-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-syriac-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-thai-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/libconf/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-tibetan-fc.so
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin/vmware-checkvm
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/xorg/xorg-generic.conf
/usr/share/selinux/devel/include/apps/vmware.if
/usr/share/selinux/targeted/vmware.pp.bz2
/var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/6Server/vmware_tools_rhel6
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1c5aa178dc2d0d4506e0293898e5f7107290d56e-vmware-tools-libraries-x-8.6.0-2-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/1f7f8aeddb8ad8f1a361f33c9e4d8b919d7f2b2b-vmware-tools-foundation-8.6.0-4-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/v/9c6c48687a70f79c20c8e689fa1b1f0ad172190e-vmware-tools-libraries-nox-8.6.0-2-x86_64/releasever
[root@tst-01 ~]#
```

It seems there are no VMWare Tools processes, but there are VMWare Tools packages installed.

I would rather deploy VMWare Tools to all servers distributing packages. Can somebody confirm if VMWare Tools is correctly installed or not on this server?

Comment: What does `lsmod` say? It should have the kernel module there.

Comment: How did you install the VMware tools?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a healthy system, you should see the `vmtoolsd` daemon:

```
[root@xt ~]# ps aux | grep vm
root       381  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun23   0:00 [vmw_pvscsi_wq_2]
root      1319  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun23   0:18 [vmmemctl]
root      2315  0.0  0.0  69540  1960 ?        Sl   Jun23  14:43 /usr/sbin/vmtoolsd
```

Please also see: [How to detect, in the guest operating system, if the vmware tools are out of date?](https://serverfault.com/questions/506618/how-to-detect-in-the-guest-operating-system-if-the-vmware-tools-are-out-of-dat/506627#506627)

One of the interesting options for VMware installations now is the use of the [VMware Operating System Specific Packages](http://www.vmware.com/download/packages.html) (OSPs) instead of managing the guest tools through the vSphere console.

This enables tools management independent of your vSphere version, and allows distribution through your operating system's native package manager.

Comment: This is very interesing. Can you show the output from `rpm -qa|grep -i vmware` and `dpkg --get-selections|grep -i vmware` if you have such?