# Possible to install vmware tools 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

According to this [pdf](http://packages.vmware.com/tools/docs/manuals/osp-esxi-51-install-guide.pdf), it should be possible to install vmware tools 5.5 for Ubuntu 5.5, but the kernel versions doesn't match for `vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-29-generic-pae` and the latest Ubuntu kernel is `2.6.32-53`.

**question**

Have anyone been able to install it?

This is the intended howto

```
wget http://packages.vmware.com/tools/keys/VMWARE-PACKAGING-GPG-DSA-KEY.pub -O  /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/VMWARE-PACKAGING-GPG-DSA-KEY.pub

apt-key add /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/VMWARE-PACKAGING-GPG-DSA-KEY.pub
mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.5/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vmware-tools.list

apt-get update
apt-get install vmware-tools-esx-kmods-$(uname -r)
apt-get install vmware-tools-esx vmware-tools-esx-nox
```

Comment: I'm glad I don't use Ubuntu for this.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use [open-vm-tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools)? It's part of the standard distribution.

Comment: @GeraldCombs Apparently VMware sees these a 3rd party tools, and doesn't expose the same functionality as their own. Although I don't understand why, as the open-vm-tools is also from VMware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's okay to use open-vm-tools or things that register as "third-party" VMware tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2011350). Why do you say that they don't expose the same functionality? It just means that the VMware tools can't be managed by vSphere ([which is fine for me](https://serverfault.com/questions/521915/how-do-i-make-sure-vmware-tools-is-installed-and-running/521920#521920)).

You should care about the memory ballooning features and the guest power options. That's what matters. It's also what's enabled in the SuSE-based appliances distributed by VMware. See below:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I can't use the Power features in the right click menu on the VM's on those VM's that says "3rd party unsupported". However I don't see the `vmtoolsd` process either on my Ubuntu 12.04 VM's. How do you install the vmtools on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember very well, but I first installed all required vmware packages mentioned in the the PDF you are referencing with apt (`deb http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.0latest/ubuntu precise main`), including vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-29-generic. This shouldn't be a problem because there are not dependency to the kernel, but I'm not sure.

Then I installed all vmware-tools kernel module sources. I have the following installed:

```
ii  vmware-tools-vmblock-modules-source                   1.1.2.0-1.precise            Contains the source needed to build the vmblock kernel module package (kmp) for the running kernel.
ii  vmware-tools-vmci-modules-source                      9.0.3.0-1.precise            Contains the source needed to build the vmci kernel module package (kmp) for the running kernel.
ii  vmware-tools-vmhgfs-modules-source                    1.4.1.1-1.precise            Contains the source needed to build the vmhgfs kernel module package (kmp) for the running kernel.
ii  vmware-tools-vmsync-modules-source                    1.1.0.1-1.precise            Contains the source needed to build the vmsync kernel module package (kmp) for the running kernel.
ii  vmware-tools-vmxnet-modules-source                    2.0.9.2-1.precise            Contains the source needed to build the vmxnet kernel module package (kmp) for the running kernel.
ii  vmware-tools-vsock-modules-source                     1.0.0.0-1.precise            Contains the source needed to build the vsock kernel module package (kmp) for the running kernel.
```

Finally I use the following script to update to the running kernel version:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service vmware-tools-services stop
for a in vmhgfs vsock vmsync vmblock vmci
do
   sudo service $a stop
done
sudo module-assistant build vmware-tools-{vmxnet,vmsync,vmci,vmblock}-modules-source
sudo module-assistant install vmware-tools-{vmxnet,vmsync,vmci,vmblock}-modules-source
sudo module-assistant build vmware-tools-{vsock,vmhgfs}-modules-source
sudo module-assistant install vmware-tools-{vsock,vmhgfs}-modules-source
sudo service vmware-tools-services start
for a in vmhgfs vsock vmsync vmblock vmci
do
   sudo service $a start
done
```