# VMware Tools are installed but inactive. Scientific Linux 6.4, ESXi 5.1.0, vCenter 5.1.0

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, scientific-linux, vmware-tools

Basic information:

- VM OS is Scientific Linux 6.4 x86_64, installed as minimal, with network-support and access to EPEL repository.
- Hypervisor is ESXI 5.1.0, build-1065491. I don't have the rights needed for the upgrade to latest version.
- vCenter is 5.1.0.

I installed perl, then used [the official manual installation procedure for Linux-based OS](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware-tools-installation-configuration.pdf). The script vmware-install.pl proceeded without errors. I then followed the post-install instructions and rebooted my VM.

In vSphere, vmware-tools are installed but inactive.

In the VM, I ran vmware-toolbox-cmd, and vmware-tools are installed and up to date. They are just not working.

**Have I missed something? What do I need to do to get them working?**

Comment: Can you provide the ESXi version and build number?

Comment: vmware -vl got me "VMware ESXi 5.1.0 build-1065491". Edited question too.

Comment: Found that it was possible to install from [Operating System Specific Packages](http://serverfault.com/questions/506618/how-to-detect-in-the-guest-operating-system-if-the-vmware-tools-are-out-of-dat/506627#506627), i'll try that later.

Answer (score 1):

I was just going to advise the OSP option, but the real fix is probably [upgrading your ESXi host to the current revision/patch level](https://serverfault.com/questions/399462/are-vmware-esxi-5-patches-cumulative). As of this writing, your build number is **1065491**, and the current is **1483097**.

VMware Tools often get incremented in the ESXi patch releases. It makes sense to keep your hosts up to date.

Comment: Well, I'm not the one in charge of ESXI hosts in my society. I'll suggest that to the one responsible, but the manual installation through vCenter use the vmware-tools corresponding to your ESXI version+build, so the problem should not logically come from there...
Anyway, after going through the OSPs solution, the vmware-tools are working.
I still don't know where exactly the problem could have originated from.

Comment: @Lysarion The right fix is still an update of the hosts. 1065491 is from April 2013, so it's old. But if you can't do that, run with the OSPs, since it gives you more control over the VM's tools. Either approach will solve your problem.