# Linux VMWare Tools build for running kernel or latest installed kernel?

Tags: linux, vmware-vsphere, rhel6, vmware-tools

I haven't been able to find any information regarding when building VMWare Tools on Linux whether it builds against the currently running kernel or the latest installed kernel.

To clarify (hopefully): If I have a VM running RHEL 6 running kernel 2.6.32-358 and have installed kernel 2.6.32-431 but not rebooted to make it active, if I then build VMWare Tools which kernel will it build for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VMware tools, as installed via the vSphere client, will build against the currently-running kernel, not the latest kernel on the server.

If using a support OS (like RHEL6), you should avoid this entirely and use the [VMware Operating System Specific Packages](https://www.vmware.com/support/packages) (OSPs), as they're managed via your package manager and can be updated independently of your ESXi releases/patches.

[How to detect, in the guest operating system, if the vmware tools are out of date?](https://serverfault.com/questions/506618/how-to-detect-in-the-guest-operating-system-if-the-vmware-tools-are-out-of-dat/506627#506627)

Comment: Thank you for the additional info about OSPs. Surprisingly I had not seen that mentioned in my searches.